# I want to open the Roomle Configurator already in EDIT mode on a mobile device

Tags: roomle

I would like the Roomle Configurator to always open in EDIT mode rather than VIEW only on a mobile device, how to I force this to happen? I've read the documentation but don't seem to be able to make it work, this is my current code...

```
   <script type="module">
            import RoomleConfiguratorApi from 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0441/4531/1894/files/roomle-configurator-api.es.min.js';
               (async ()=> {
                const options = {
                translations: {
                        en: {
                          params: {
                            'request-product': 'Add to Cart'
                            },
                            addons:{
                            'hint':'All builds should have at least one rear panel to aid stability. All 
   sizes in centimetres'
                            },
                            "global": {
   "gdpr-info": "I agree to receiving emails about my saved design, as well as the occasional piece of 
   carefully curated content from Shelved. The data controller is Roomle GmbH. Your data will be 
   processed in order to allow you to finish and save your design. The legal basis for the processing is 
   your consent (art. 6(1)(a)(f) of the GDPR).",

   }
                        }
                        },
                    id: 'racksystems_test:sub_root',
                    locale: 'en', 
   overrideCountry: 'en', 
   overrideTenant: '114', 
   usePriceService: false,
   emails: true,
   deeplink: 'https://www.shelved.co.uk/pages/product-configurator? 
  roomleId=#CONFIGURATIONID#&configuratorId=racksystems',



                };
                const configurator = await RoomleConfiguratorApi.create(
                    'rackSystems',
                    document.getElementById('configurator-container'),
                    options,
                    
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

After you obtained the configurator instance with `RoomleConfigurator.create` you can use `configurator.ui.startConfiguring()` to open it immediately.

You can find an example here: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#typescript

And here you'll find the documentation: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/api/classes/exposed_api.exposedapi.html#startconfiguring

Comment: Hi @teh.fonsi ... How can we achieve this using iOS mobile SDK. I use `rubensView.loadConfiguration(catalogItem.configuration)` line of code to load the 3D object.

Comment: startConfiguring() was recently added to the iOS framework: https://docs.roomle.com/ios/rubens/classes/RubensConfiguratorView.html#startconfiguring

Comment: Thanks! I found it in the doc, However, it works only if I call `startConfiguring()` with delay of 5 seconds just after `loadConfiguration`. I could not find any event or delegate like `configurationDidFinishLoading`. Is there something which I missed?